# __init__ method missing positional argument even though it is clearly passed

Tags: python, kivy, initialization, arguments, init

I have a custom widget `PlaylistView` in kivy which should take another custom widget as argument for its **init** method:

```
class PlaylistView(Widget):
    def __init__(self, node, **kwargs):  # (originally:) node: GridNode,...  (custom node, removed for min. reproducable exmple but still yields the same error)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.node = node
        ...
```

But whenever I try to create an instance of it, for example: `PlaylistView(1)`, `PlaylistView(GridNode('test'))` or `PlaylistView("test")` (no matter what I pass as argument), I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Maximilian.Wolf/PycharmProjects/MiaudioPyler/main.py", line 215, in <module>
     PlaylistView("test")
   File "C:/Users/Maximilian.Wolf/PycharmProjects/MiaudioPyler/main.py", line 157, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Maximilian.Wolf\Miniconda3\envs\MiaudioPyler\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 359, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\Maximilian.Wolf\Miniconda3\envs\MiaudioPyler\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\Maximilian.Wolf\Miniconda3\envs\MiaudioPyler\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 541, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Maximilian.Wolf\Miniconda3\envs\MiaudioPyler\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 663, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Maximilian.Wolf\Miniconda3\envs\MiaudioPyler\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'node'
```

I also tried using `node=None` in init, same results.

Could this be something to do with kivy or how I call `super().__init__`?
**EDIT**
I tried this seperately, which works, still no clue what's causing the error.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class PlaylistView(Widget):
    def __init__(self, node, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.node = node

PlaylistView(1)
```

**EDIT 2**
More info:
What I did and wasn't showing in the example is loading a bunch of kv-files with `Builder.load_file(..`. Commenting this out also makes the error go away.

Comment: Have you tried using `super().__init__(node, **kwargs)`?

Comment: Yes, but that's an unexpected Argument. I don't want to pass it to the Widget class and its constructor doesn't have that parameter, so I if I do this I get: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Something's wrong in code you haven't shown us. We can't tell what, because you haven't shown us. Post a [mcve].

Comment: What is the difference between the original code and the first edit? I don't see it.

Comment: The code from edit 2 was missing in edit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback must be read from top to bottom. The error is is file "C:\Users\Maximilian.Wolf\Miniconda3\envs\MiaudioPyler\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659.
The line

```
child = cls(__no_builder=True)
```

is triggering the error. Since kivy uses factories, it is not clear what is causing the error, but the parameter is missing in that call, and *not* in your call to `super().__init__`.

You should also include `*args` in the signature and call to super: factories may use the function signatures.

Comment: *args didn't help. But as you said the error was caused by something different, another class had 'node' as an argument when it shouldn't have. I figured out what the bug was by looking at which class the Builder was dealing with when it raised the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
def __init__(self, node): 
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
```

Comment: This just hides the error by piling *another* bug on top of whatever the original bug was. `super(Widget, self).__init__()` **skips** `Widget.__init__` - the first argument to `super` is a class to skip past, not the class where the method should be found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).